# NoSQL databases: what about read consistency?

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, acid, oracle-nosql, nosql

From what I can make out NoSQL databases might be a good option for high intensity data read applications, but are a less good fit if you need to do also do a lot data updates and transactionality is very important to you (what with there being no ACID compliance). Right? Too simplistic maybe.

But anyway, supposing I'm partly right at least I'm now concerned about how NoSQL databases maintain a "read consistent" view of the data that you're either reading or writing. Or do they? And if they don't, isn't that a really big problem?

I mean, if the data that you're reading (or updating) is changing as you read it then you're potentially going to get an inconsistent/dirty result set. Coming from an Oracle rdbms background, where all this is just handled for you, I find it confusing how the lack of read consistency is anything but a big problem. Could well be though that I'm missing some key point about all this. Can someone set me straight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB allows the application to select the desired level of read consistency using "write concern". This concept allows your application to block until a certain condition is met for a given write.

By way of example, you can consider any write successful so long as the operation is communicated to a master server. Alternatively, you can block until a write has been propagated to a majority of nodes in your replica set. In this way, you can mix performance/consistency to taste.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Like, could you provide some documentation reference of such configuration?

Answer (score 5):

I am a developer on the Oracle NoSQL Database and will answer your question relative to that particular NoSQL system.

The Oracle NoSQL Database API allows the programmer to specify -- with each API call -- the level of read consistency.  The four possible values, ranging from strictest to loosest, are Absolute, Time, Version, and None.  Absolute says to always read from the replication master so that the most current value is returned.  "Time" says that the system can return a value from any replica that is at least within a certain time delta of the master (e.g. read the value from any replica that is within 2 seconds of the master).  Every read and write call to the system returns a "version handle".  This version handle may be passed into any read call when Consistency.Version is specified and it tells the system to read from any replica which is at least as up to date as that version.  This is useful for Read Modify Write (aka CAS) scenarios.  The last value, Consistency.None says that any replica can be used (i.e. there is no consistency guaranteed).

I hope this is helpful.

Charles Lamb

Answer (score 3):

A NoSQL database can be read-consistent, although it's generally not a big problem if it's not strictly so, check out the [CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem). There's been quite a lot of research done in this area, I recommend reading [Amazon's Dynamo paper](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/files/amazon-dynamo-sosp2007.pdf) for a quick view of some of the problems and solutions faced by distributed systems like NoSQL databases.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the NoSQL database you are using as each implements a different strategy. You can read, for example, [Riak's explanation](http://wiki.basho.com/Eventual-Consistency.html) of their "eventual consistency" model or Lars Hofhansel's writeup on [ACID in HBase](http://hadoop-hbase.blogspot.com/2012/03/acid-in-hbase.html)